# Select a string text from .txt file then check the status

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check this file .txt, it's a disk health report.

My goal is to select a single Line:   Health Status : Good (100 %)

Then

I have to check the status:

```
If -eq (100 %)  write-host Ok

If -ne  (100 %)  write-host Errors on the disk !!!
```

I wrote this, but then i don't know how to select (xxx %) value and check it

```
$errorCounts = Get-Content c:\b.txt | 
Select-String "Health Status : " -AllMatches | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
Foreach-Object { $_.Groups[0].Value }

write-host $errorCounts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$HealthPercent = Select-String -Pattern 'Health Status :.+\((\d+) %' -Path .\q.txt | 
                     ForEach-Object {[int]$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```